# GVIM User Interface

Tags: vim, vi

I have been using Vi and Gvim for several years now. I have visual problems so I lean to editors that I can actually see the editing controls (UI). One thing that has been an on-going problem is Gvim, no matter what I try I cannot get it to display a larger UI so I can readily see the editing controls.

I have spent years researching this and short of compiling Vim for myself I have basically given up, I feel there is no solution. Am I wrong? Can the UI items be controlled under Linux/AIX/BSD/Window/MacOSX (list your favorite platform here...)

Comment: Most Vim users don't use menus or buttons. If you have been using Vim for several years I doubt you need those menus. My Vim (GUI or TUI) is just a beautiful dark grey rectangle with no UI besides scrollbars: no UI, no problem.

Comment: @romainl +1 for `just a beautiful dark grey rectangle` :D :D

Comment: @romainl - Hence why I stick to plain ol' boring vi :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the gtk2-UI you can do following:
Create an env variable named `GTK2_RC_FILES` pointing to a file (usually `~/.gtkrc-2.0`).
(Edit: this location seems to be the default, so it doesn't require the env variable, at least an linux)

To change the font size globally add this:

```
gtk-font-name = "Sans 30"
```

(Of course, adjust to your liking)

To change the size only for the gvim menubar:

```
style "vim" {
  font_name = "Sans 40"
}

widget "*vim-menubar*" style "vim"
```

(Important: the style definition has to be before it's usage)

To use it for the whole of vim replace `vim-menubar` with `vim-main-window`.
There is are also `vim-toolbar` and `vim-balloon-label`. You can grep the source code for `gtk_widget_set_name`.

Edit: It seems, you can simply specify a custom size, the family stays whatever it was before.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know about .gtkrc-2.0 -- that gives me new study's  :)

Comment: If you don't mind affecting all GTK apps, you can probably just use gnome-control-center to change your desktop fonts.  Of course this assumes you are using vim-gtk (gvim can also be compiled to use KDE/QT or Motif widgets).

Comment: @joeytwiddle are you sure about kde/qt? the docs don't mention qt and to kde there is "There is no KDE version of Vim. ..."

Comment: @CCSH the docs are quite sparse, you might want to look at http://www.orford.org/gtk/ and https://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes.
And please post any useful links you find on this topic here :-)

Comment: @t-8ch There used to be KDE and Motif packages in Debian and Gentoo, but they may have disappeared by now.  You can give this a try: https://bitbucket.org/equalsraf/vim-qt/src